# Rails params explained?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could anyone explain `params` in Rails controller: where they come from, and what they are referencing?

```
  def create
    @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote])
    item = params[:vote][:item_id]
    uid = params[:vote][:user_id]
    @extant = Vote.find(:last, :conditions => ["item_id = ? AND user_id = ?", item, uid])
    last_vote_time = @extant.created_at unless @extant.blank?
    curr_time = Time.now
  end
```

I would like to be able to read this code line-by-line and understand what's going on.

Comment: What's your background on server side web development? What technologies do you already know?

Comment: I've been with HTML and CSS for years. Taken classes which used PHP, JS, and Java. Used very little MVC with php though. I really learned programming using Java. And I thoroughly understand database theory.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The params come from the user's browser when they request the page. For an HTTP GET request, which is the most common, the params are encoded in the URL. For example, if a user's browser requested

`http://www.example.com/?foo=1&boo=octopus`

then `params[:foo]` would be "1" and `params[:boo]` would be "octopus".

In HTTP/HTML, the params are really just a series of key-value pairs where the key and the value are strings, but Ruby on Rails has a special syntax for making the params be a hash with hashes inside. For example, if the user's browser requested

`http://www.example.com/?vote[item_id]=1&vote[user_id]=2`

then `params[:vote]` would be a hash, `params[:vote][:item_id]` would be "1" and `params[:vote][:user_id]` would be "2".

The Ruby on Rails params are the equivalent of the [$_REQUEST array in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Comment: Equivalent to $_REQUEST except that $_REQUEST includes get, post and cookie data, while params only get and post data.

Comment: @renocor POST data is included in the Rails `params` hash as well. Cookie data is included in the `session` hash.

Comment: This answer leaves out one other source of params: the URL. See hammar's answer for more information.

Comment: toasterlovin, it sounds like you did not read the second sentence of my answer or look at the first example.

Comment: can values in param even be a number or is it always a string?

Comment: @AnkitDhingra...I think it will always be string as HTTP params are really only key/value pair and Rails (most probably Rack gem) parses that into hashes and arrays according to key value, but I have not seen anything of the sort which tells Rails that the value is a number.

Comment: What would be the value of `params[:foo]` if url could be like: http://www.example.com/?foo=1&boo=octopus&foo=2

Answer (score 79):

As others have pointed out, `params` values can come from the query string of a GET request, or the form data of a POST request, but there's also a third place they can come from: The path of the URL.

As you might know, Rails uses something called routes to direct requests to their corresponding controller actions. These routes may contain segments that are extracted from the URL and put into `params`. For example, if you have a route like this:

```
match 'products/:id', ...
```

Then a request to a URL like `http://example.com/products/42` will set `params[:id]` to `42`.

Comment: How do you get a second param? like /squad/id/member/id/stuff

Answer (score 51):

Params contains the following three groups of parameters:

1. **User supplied parameters**

- GET *(`http://example.com/url?param1=value1&param2=value2` will set params[:param1] and params[:param2])*
- POST *(e.g. JSON, XML will automatically be parsed and stored in params)*
- Note: By default, Rails duplicates the user supplied parameters and stores them in params[:user] if in UsersController, can be changed with wrap_parameters setting

4. **Routing parameters**

- `match '/user/:id'` *in `routes.rb` will set params[:id]*

3. **Default parameters**

- `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` is always available and contains the current controller and action

Comment: Could you expand your Note under `User supplied parameters` a little more?  For instance, an example of the params hash in the UsersController would be helpful.  Your example makes it sound like the  hash will look something like: `{first_name: "mike", user: {first_name: "mike"} ...}`  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not seeing that in rails4.  For instance, `{"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"gubHya6uQrQLjPRXhOC0RUuCRdn7NFr6CeKrbRfBSHI=", "ripe"=>"true", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"apples", "id"=>"4"}`.  Forgive me if I'm wrong, I'm a rails beginner.  According to your note, I should see: `{"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"gubHya6uQrQLjPRXhOC0RUuCRdn7NFr6CeKrbRfBSHI=", "ripe"=>"true", "apple" => {"ripe"=>"true"}, "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"apples", "id"=>"4"}`  I don't know if that has to do with _strong parameters_ in rails4 or not.

Comment: I am seeing the duplicated params in Rails 4, but only under json POST requests (using Angularjs) not under Rails own HTML posts.  This link explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774972/rails-wrap-parameters-vs-include-root-in-json-what-is-the-difference

Answer (score 13):

Basically, parameters are user specified data to rails application.

When you post a form, you do it generally with POST request as opposed to GET request. You can think normal rails requests as GET requests, when you browse the site, if it helps.

When you submit a form, the control is thrown back to the application. How do you get the values you have submitted to the form? `params` is how.

About your code. `@vote = Vote.new params[:vote]` creates new Vote to database using data of params[:vote]. Given your form user submitted was named under name :vote, all data of it is in this :vote field of the hash.

Next two lines are used to get item and uid user has submitted to the form.

```
@extant = Vote.find(:last, :conditions => ["item_id = ? AND user_id = ?", item, uid])
```

finds newest, or last inserted, vote from database with conditions item_id = item and user_id = uid.

Next lines takes last vote time and current time.

Answer (score 9):

On the Rails side, `params` is a method that returns an `ActionController::Parameters` object. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44070358/5462485

Comment: +1 for clarifying that `params` is a method. Ruby can make it difficult to distinguish variables from methods