# I'm Unsure on Params Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am trying to get to grips with the params hash in RoR.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but my understanding so far is that the params hash is a hash containing either form entered data or query string data related to a POST request. Where `params[:item]` creates a symbol where the relevant POST data/query is stored.  Again not sure if I'm correct on this, any enlightenment would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This SO post may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The params hash is described in detail in the [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters). TL;DR: the params hash holds all GET or POST parameters passed to the controller, as well as the :controller and :action keys.

Comment: thanks I think I was just being thrown by the use of the params part, it makes a lot more sense when attached to the HTTP context.