# Rails wrap_parameters vs include_root_in_json, what is the difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In a new Rails 3.2 app you can find in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb the following lines:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
end

# Disable root element in JSON by default.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

My understanding for the second code block is that if you convert a object to json, it will not include a root node (i.e. users => {:name => 'John'}, rather it will be just {:name => 'john'}

What then does the first wrap_parameters block do? It acts on action_controller.. why?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`include_root_in_json` is to wrap json instantiated in Rails

`wrap_parameters` is to wrap json received from a request.

If you have `wrap_parameters` enabled, and if you send the following json through a POST command to Rails:

`{name: 'John Smith'}`

Rails will automatically wrap the JSON it *received* into:

`{"person": {name: 'John Smith'}}`

`include_root_in_json`, on the other hand, is whether the json Rails **generates** from an object is wrapped or not through the `to_json` command.

---

e.g. `Person.to_json`. If `include_root_in_json` is enabled, you'll get:

`{"person": {name: 'James Brown'}}`

Otherwise, you'll just get

`{name: 'John Smith'}`

Comment: So this is what it does. Why is this default on? Should be off if doing `rails new my-app --api`