# Why Rails messing with params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I do `POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/clients` with the following request payload:

```
{"name": "David Smith", "email": "david@site.com"}
```

Both Firefox and Chrome clearly show that this is the payload.

But, in the Rails logs I see:

> Started POST "/api/clients" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-05 20:59:52 +1100
>   Processing by ClientsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"name"=>"David Smith", "email"=>"david@site.com", "client"=>{"name"=>"David Smith", "email"=>"david@site.com"}}

Indeed, if I print out `params` in `ClientsController#create`, I see that it contains the key `client`.

How does the `"client"=>{"name"=>"David Smith", "email"=>"david@site.com"}` part become part of `params`? Why Rails messing with `params`?

I use Rails 4.0.2.

---

The request is made using AngularJS:

```
ClientsNewCtrl = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', ($scope, $http, $q) ->
  $scope.client =
    name: ''
    email: ''

  $scope.createNewClient = ->
    defer = $q.defer()

    $http.post('/api/clients', $scope.client).success ->
      console.log 'Success!'
      defer.resolve()
    .error (errors, status) ->
      errors = ["Couldn't create the client."] if status != 422
      console.log errors
      defer.reject(errors)

    defer.promise
]
```

---

Here is the example that I created to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/moroshko/rails-params

1. `rails s`
2. Go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
3. Open browser's console to observe the request
4. Enter name, email and click <kbd>Create</kbd>
5. Check out Rails logs to see that `params` have the extra `client` key

Comment: How did you create those params? Form or in the URL directly?

Comment: I think that rails has a functionality to auto-wrap parameters for JSON requests, but yours looks like its HTML, so that should not be an issue here. Are you submitting the form through a browser? Have you looked into the request body through the developer console?

Comment: I NEVER experienced Rails messing with params in any way. I see from your SO profile that you're experienced with Rails, but still would rather expect it's your mistake. Do you use strong params, code you're referencing is before/after filtering? How does the form/request look?

Comment: I made a new Rails project with a `Client` form object that takes a `name` and `email` parameter and the params appear as expected. Can you post your view and your controller?

Comment: @JohnFeminella: I created an example to demonstrate the issue. Please see the updated question.

Comment: If you're talking about the form here https://github.com/moroshko/rails-params/blob/master/app/views/clients/_form.html.erb I would expect them to be submitted as part of the `client` key, as you have a form_for a Client object.

Comment: @sevenseacat: This code isn't actually used (was generated by Rails scaffold). I cleaned the repo now. Please see the updated code.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods.html#method-i-wrap_parameters rails does "mess" with your parameters

Comment: @MishaMoroshko learned that on StackOverflow as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, Rails messing with request `params` as specified by default in `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

To stop this behavior, one could do:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

Relevant info:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods.html#method-i-wrap_parameters
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775570/247243