# checking the form data received in ruby on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, to-yaml

I want to check the form data received from the form in ruby on rails controller.

I tried this but nothing is shown:

```
@user.to_yaml
```

where `@user` is the form name(`<%=form_for @user` )

Comment: Check the server log when you hit the submit but there is Parameters hash which would be generated in it..

Comment: How to check the server log? is it the one shown on console?

Comment: yess...you can also use debugger gem to see the params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data sent by a form is stored in the `params` hash (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained) for more information).

also, in development, just put a `raise` in your controller action to show an error page with all request parameters displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct. but will like to change something

```
all the details are stored in params only
```

and it will be better to show those in flash by doing
      flash.notice = params

as it will not effect the working of app

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check out the server log on the console or use the debugger gem that would keep track of the params and the files along which the request moves along...