# Rails - Submit Values based on Multiple Selection and Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, submit, textfield

I'm still new in Rails. I'm trying to have a page where a user can select multiple items from a list then add some description into a text field. And at the end, the user should submit this information. How can I retrieve submitted data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here's the code for now:

```
<select multiple >
  <option>Table</option>
  <option>Door</option>
</select>

<br><br><br>
<select multiple >
  <option>Blue</option>
  <option>Red</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="post_user" name="post" size="20" value="" />
```

Comment: You will retrieve the submitted data in the method of the controller where you are submitting this form. Can you show what have you tried in your controller so far?

Answer (score 1):

All the form (POST) data can be found in the params hash. See attached links for details:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters

[Rails params explained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained)