# Rails id parameter not persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, essentially, I have two models, Ticket

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
end
```

And Event:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :club
    has_many :tickets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets
end
```

They are associated with each other, and I have done the necessary migrations.

In the events/show view, it shows the event and then at the end I have a link to create a ticket, with this event's name passed as an id:

```
<%= link_to 'Add tickets', new_ticket_path(:id => @event.name) %>
```

This renders properly in the new ticket page, I have tested it in the new ticket view with `<%= params[:id] %>` and it comes up correctly.

The tickets_controller's `create` method is as follows:

```
def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.event_id = params[:id]
    ...
end
```

But when testing back in the events/show view

```
<% @tickets = Ticket.all %>
    <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
    <p><%= ticket.event_id %>--</p>
<% end %>
```

All of the event_id's come up empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try and output the content of params at the beginning of your create action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're passing the `:id` param to the `new` method, and then expecting it to persist to the `create` method

[Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained) are HTTP-based values -- they don't last longer than a single request. You'll have to either use a [`nested resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), or set the `event_id` attribute in your `new` form:

---

**Route**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :events do
    resources :tickets #-> /events/:event_id/tickets/new
end
```

This will keep the `params[:event_id]` param consistent (as it's being passed in the URL), allowing you to use it in your `create` action like so:

```
def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.event_id = params[:event_id]
    ...
end
```

This is the conventional way to do this

---

**Attribute**

If you want to just test your code, you should set the `event_id` param in your `new` action form:

```
<%= form_for [@event, @ticket] do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden :event_id, params[:id] %> #-> sets params[:ticket][:event_id]
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to set the `event_id` param in your `strong_params` method in your create action:

```
def new
   @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
   @ticket = Ticket.new
end

def create
   @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
   @ticket.save
end

private

def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:event_id)
end
```

Comment: I have followed all of your instructions, but the event_id is now 0. So better than nothing, but not coming up with the id

Comment: Okay, at least it's coming up with something. Which method did you use? Routes or hidden field?

Comment: I used both and individually but still no luck

Comment: Wanna go to chat? I was confident with my answer, so I want to see what's up!

Comment: How do you chat here?