# creating has_one association error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create and order that is associated with an item.

An Order has one item:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :item
end
```

An Item belongs to an order:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

According to the guide this should work:

```
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
```

I have this in my controller:

```
def create
    @order = @current_item.build_order(order_params)
    @order.save
    redirect_to @order
end
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

**undefined method `build_order' for nil:NilClass**

I know this has to do with how I've defined current_items but I've tried many different things and all lead to this same error message.

I have this in my application helper:

```
def current_item
   Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

Can anyone point me in a better direction for how to define this or what I'm doing wrong here.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: `@current_item` != `current_item`. One is a method call, one is an instance variable.

Answer (score 3):

1) You don't have access to a helper method from the controller. You can include the helper class in your controller but it's a really bad practice. You must use helper methods only in the views.

2) You can move `current_item` method from the helper to the controller. Then there will be another problem. In your `create` method, you are trying to access instance variable `@current_item` which is not initialized at the moment, not the method. You can do it this way:

```
@order = @current_item.build_order(order_params)
```

to

```
@order = current_item.build_order(order_params)
```

Then `current_item` will return you Item object.

3) I am not sure what are your params, but you can implement it this way:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  @order.save
  redirect_to @order
end
```

where params[:order] is for example:

```
{name: "order 1", item_id: 1}
```

Comment: Thanks Mihail.  I think I'm closer.  The problem is I don't just want access to the item_id, but all of the other attributes of item.  @order.item_name, order.item_price in my order views.  My problem now is when I define current_item as I did in my question (but move it to the controller) I'm still getting an error "Couldn't find Item without an ID".  Thanks again for you help!

Comment: You don't need `current_item` method. Put all logic in the `create` method.
On which line is the error raised? If it is on this line: Item.find(params[:id]), check your params object, maybe :id is missing.

Comment: @Kelly I don't mean any offense, and if I'm incorrect here I apologize, but it sounds like what would really help you is a little refresher on params and how to assign them: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained) is the best explanation of params I have found (of course it's on SO). I think Mihail has a great solution for you above, but you've got to get your params down to make it work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `create` to use a method, rather a variable, so modify it as follows:

```
def create
  @order = current_item.build_order(order_params)
  @order.save
  redirect_to @order
end 

# rest of code

def current_item
  Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

This should help.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  When I implement this I get the following error  "Couldn't find Item without an ID"  Do you suggest any other way that I could find the item that the user is currently viewing?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is being caused by trying to run `Item.find(params[:id])` but not passing it a valid value. It seems that params[:id] is maybe nil? Can you confirm this using a debugger or by temporarily adding `raise "Params[:id] is set to #{params[:id]}` to the first line of the method, running the code and seeing what it says in the terminal output?

All you need to do make this work is have a parameter value for the item come from the form that is being submitted. Normally rails uses the route/url to populate the value of params[:id]. For example, when the request is `GET /items/1`, params[:id] is 1.

In this case though, unless you've done some custom routing that you haven't shown in your question, creating a new order would usually be a POST to /orders and since there is no id in the url, params[:id] is nil.

It's up to you to add the item id from the order form. It would make sense that it would be sent with the rest of the order params as `item_id`, rather than just `id`, since `id` is usually used to reference the current object, which is a new order and therefore doesn't get have an id.

You'll need to make sure that item_id is whitelisted in your strong params with the rest of the values in the order_params method (I assume you defined this in the same controller but did not show it in the code), and then the code would look something like this.

```
def create
  @order = current_item.build_order(order_params)
  @order.save
  redirect_to @order
end 

#note the changes the the argument
def current_item
  Item.find(order_params[:item_id])
end

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:item_id, :other_values_that_you_send)
end
```