# Rails 4 - Passing user input back to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails newbie here looking for some advice.

I have a basic page with a form and a submit button. When the user hits the submit button, I want to display what was inputted back the user on the same page with some appended text. For example, if the user inputs "jack", then underneath the form I want the string "hello jack!" to be displayed.

How do i pass what is submitted in my view to the controller, append some text, then display back to the page? Note: I don't want to store the input in a database.

Here's what I've got so far, any guidance would be great!

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'home' => 'pages#index'
end
```

My Controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
def home
end
end
```

My view

```
<h1> Enter some text </h1>
<%= form_tag("/home", method: "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if params[:q].present?
      @input = "hello #{params[:q]}!" 
    end
  end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_tag("/home", method: "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q, @input) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
```

[`How params works in Rails`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6886073/2057388)

Comment: Thanks  @Зелёный  with that form code I am getting the error /Users/Jack/RailsApp/app/views/pages/index.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...er.append=( text_field_tag(:q), input );output_buffer.safe... ... ^ -- any ideas?

Comment: you have a syntax error. i added an excess brackets. Check updated answer