# Rails Tutorial Ch12 - query about params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Chapter 12 is all about adding a way to reset password. In the beginning we create a controller called PasswordResets.

For the create action, the method is defined as:

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

My question is: how is the key [:password_reset] for params created? Was it always there and did we do something to make it present?

Params is something I find a bit confusing and can't get my head around!

Comment: It would help if you said what tutorial you're referencing!

Comment: Please refer this to understand params. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained

Comment: Talking about Hartl's tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about **Michael Hartl's** Rails tutorial:
you can see in password reset form's code there there is line like below to generate form:

```
<%= form_for(:password_reset, url: password_resets_path) do |f| %>
```

and `email` field is like `<%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>`

so while rendering form, Rails will render forms name in format of `form_name[field_name]` so the email field name becomes `password_reset[email]`. When you access the params in controller, you get the `email` params value which is inside of `password_reset` params since `params` is a basic `ruby hash` so your code becomes `params[:password_reset][:email]`. If you want then you can change the form name, just change `password_reset` in `form_for` to `reset` or something you like and you will access it like `params[:reset][:email]`

I hope you understood my point. I am not good at explaining.

Comment: So by adding `:password_reset` in :

Comment: So by adding `:password_reset` in `<%= form_for(:password_reset, url: password_resets_path) do |f| %>` we create a params key of `[:password_reset]`? By that logic does that also mean if I wrote `<%= form_for(:xxx, url: password_resets_path) do |f| %>`, I create params key of `[:xxx]`?

Comment: yes. since you are learning its a better way to learn by experimenting. Try changing that in your form and see what happens. If you found something odd then feel free to comment here

Comment: When I goto the "Forgot Password" form and submit invalid email address, this is what I get: ` xxx: !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters`. Seems to work?

Comment: It showing that `xxx` is a ruby object of of type `ActionController::Parameters` so nothing wrong in it. where are you seeing it ? Do you mean your are not getting required functionality ?

Comment: No I mean it is working. I see that xxx is an object of ActionController::Parameters, so it seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome. Keep learning and experimenting. I learned from Hartl's tutorial too. Though I had other sources

Comment: I've been trying to learn full stack web dev from scratch for 2 months now. starting with Ruby, HTML, CSS and JS. What do you recommend next after Hartl's?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125689/discussion-between-sajan-and-joseph-liu).